# List LI items and wrap over when taller than parent container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list if `li` elements that i would like to wrap over when it reaches the height of the parent element WITHOUT scroll bars.

What is the best way to achieve this?

css

```
ul{height:90px; width:100%; display:block; background-color:grey;}
li{height:20px; width:60px; background-color:red;}
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

heres my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/LX4Nb/

currently it looks like this 
[image]

would like it to look like this
[image]

**edit**  it looks like a css solution is only possible above ie9.  any jquery ideas please.
thank you

Comment: What do you mean you want them to wrap over? like still be able to scroll through them without the bars? or just completely hidden?

Comment: Are you trying to stack the `li` elements left-to-right and then down, or top-to-bottom and then right?

Comment: I feel a JQ/JQ solution coming. I think it's meant to be top down, then move across and then down again.

Comment: @Kierchon made jpgs of `overflow`,  sorry for being vague

Comment: Are you widths and height required to be dynamic? It's barely possible if the numbers are static.

Comment: @Paulie_D currently the numbers are static.  for a JQ solution do you recommend adding height of each li and calculating against containers fixed height?

Comment: @MarcAudet  top-to-bottom and then right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use columns. But granted this doesn't work in IE9 or below.
`ul{column-count:3; -webkit-column-count:3; -moz-column-count:3;height:90px; width:100%; display:block; background-color:grey;}`

This solution unfortunately does not allow for auto columns, meaning it will always have that number of columns and make the content fit.

Comment: i see,  do you know of any ie9 and below hacks?

Comment: @tq, as Paulie_D pointed out in his comment, this may actually require you to use JQuery/JS solution.

Comment: I believe that you can ignore the `column-count` property and just use `column-width` and it will auto adjust...so `column-width:50%` MIGHT work...haven't tested it though.

Comment: You still need the `column-count` property. `column-width` applies to the columns that are created with `column-count`.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: You edited the question after I answered.

Add this to your `li` tag to give you 2 columns

```
float:left;
width:50%;
```

or this to give you three columns

```
float:left;
width:33.3%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LX4Nb/4/

Comment: that hides the `overflow`,  i want to `overflow` to wrap over

Comment: That just hides the `li` and does nothing to meet the requirements.

Comment: float left will not make columns

Comment: @tq setting the width as well as float will make them fit into the parent making them appear like columns.

Comment: It might make them fit but will it put them in the right order?